# how to use gmail account to send mails?

Tags: asp.net

I created gmail account to use it to send mails but no any mails (without any exception) sent code snippet:

public static bool SendEmail(string _FromEmail, string _ToEmail, string _Subject, string _EmailBody)
    {

```
    try
    {


        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
        smtpClient.Port = 465;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("my gmail account", "my password");
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.From = new MailAddress(_FromEmail);
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(_ToEmail));
        msg.Subject = _Subject;
        msg.Body = _EmailBody;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        smtpClient.Send(msg);

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            String str = ex.InnerException.ToString();

        }
        return false;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an ASP.net guy. But let me tell you something to try. Try using STARTTLS on port 587. I've got the same problem with java and I could get it solved by using STARTTLS.

Have a look at [this page](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13287)

Good luck.

Comment: when i tried to set smtpClient.EnableSsl = true; I got this exception: [System.Net.Mail.SmtpException] = {"SSL must not be enabled for pickup-directory delivery methods."}

Comment: don't enable ssl. you have to enable starttls. i'm sorry i don't know how to do that in asp.net. in java we enable strattls and authentication by "properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");" Try to find how to implement the same thing in asp.net